# Can it happen to be an unconventional usage of "would+Perfect Infinitive"?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Of course, there has been a raft of questions and answers about how to use the construction *would+Perfect Infinitive* but one I have stumbled across on the Internet plunged me into bewilderment.

I have never met such an aspect of its use in any books on English Grammar. And here it is:

"It doesn't matter whether the action would have happened in the past or in the future. You use "would have (done)" to talk about something that's about to happen:

*A: Don't forget, we have a meeting this afternoon at two.*

*B: Don't worry, I would have remembered!*"

Can it be (or I may be misinterpreting something) that the construction of B: "...I would have remembered" relates to the future implication?

I.e., is the following line true?

- *"Don't worry, I would have remembered!" = "Don't worry, I would have remembered about the meeting by half past one!" = "Don't worry, I will have remembered about the meeting by half past one!"*

If there are any references to grammar rules on this usage, please render them to me.

Comment: I take it to mean "I would have remembered even if you had not reminded me."

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you as usual and Happy New Year with all my best regards!

Comment: I would have taken it to mean exactly the same as you did. But there is the first part of the by-me-adduced pattern which is about its conditional aspect (I should have put it up to avoid ambiguity): "Whenever you hear "I would have..", you can always imagine that the sentence ends with "if ..". For example: I would have remembered (I would have remembered even if you hadn't emailed me). "I would have.." is used to talk about something that didn't really happen, but you're imagining how things would be different if something different had happened in the past." And then as in my question:

Comment: "It doesn't matter whether the action would have happened in the past or in the future. You use "would have (done)" to talk about something that's about to happen:..." From this fact I concluded that it was not the conditional that was taken up in this part.

Comment: Well, I suppose that, if B was thinking about the meeting before A spoke they would say "I haven't forgotten" - so, yes, you could say that it means "I'm confident that I would have thought about it soon without being reminded".

Comment: @Kate Bunting So I might be guessing that even for native speakers using "would+Perf. Infinitive" for the future assumption/possibility bordering on the modal's "would" volitional tint of meaning is utmostly unusual? As to me, it seems logical and founded in fact by analogy with its stronger form "will": "I think the train will leave soon/I think the train would leave soon" - "I think the train will have left as soon as all passengers are on board/I think the train would have left as soon as all passengers are on board." Am I right?

Comment: English is a great analytical language that can thus make a mess in non-native speakers' heads!

Comment: I find your book's assertion that _would have_ refers to the future rather strange. My last comment was an attempt to make sense of it. Personally, I would certainly use _will_ and not _would_ when predicting future events. "I think the train will leave as soon as all the passengers are on board," but "The train will have left by three o'clock."

Answer (score 1):

Sentence B is essentially the apodosis of a "third conditional" sentence. This requires that the protasis use the past perfect form and that the apodosis use the perfect form of the modal auxiliaries should, would, could, might, or may. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences) gives these examples of the third conditional:

> If you had called me, I would have come.
> Would he have succeeded if I had helped him?

Therefore, as KB suggested in a comment, your sentence could be understood as:

> Don't worry, [[even if you hadn't reminded me,]] I would have remembered!"

Your suggestion (changing "would" to "will") has a similar meaning, but we don't usually use the future tense in such situations.

Comment: +1 And if "would have remembered" refers to a future time (between *now* and the meeting at 2:00), then it could also be an example of the **Mixed Conditional** further down in the same source you linked. Its description of "When the condition refers to the past, but the consequence to the present" seems like a fairly close match for that situation.

Comment: @Quack E. Duck Thank you! I would compare the construction in question with the following English grammatical rule: "I wish he would arrive soon" - "I wish he would have arrived by 2 p.m. tomorrow". The latter doesn't look like the 3-d Conditional but rather like the 2-d Conditional of Present Perfect. Is it right?

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Yes, that could apply in that situation. And let's not forget that although the descriptions in that Wikipeida article are common forms of conditional sentences, they're not exhaustive.

Comment: @Eugene Your second sentence ("I wish he would have arrived by 2 p.m. tomorrow") doesn't seem right to me. However, as I just mentioned in my previous comment, English conditional sentences come in many forms, and they vary by dialect, register, etc., so that might be fine.

Comment: @Eugene It may be syntactically valid, but the word "wish" combined with a perfect tense just doesn't sound right to express the possibility of something that *may still happen*.  "I wish... A would have B" sounds like a contrary-to-fact condition until you hear "tomorrow," which is jarring.  Like MarcInManhattan said though, I don't know if this varies by dialect.  I wonder if Ngrams would turn anything up?

Comment: @Quack E. Duck, MarcInManhattan It's really nice that you are among those few native speakers who could obviously have understood my inferences. I can not understand why English speakers don't use such handy instrument as "would+perfect inf." for expressing future irrealis or future speculation/assumption. "He would have lived here for 5 years by 2024 if he hadn't left a month ago" (I don't see other means of relaying this idea). Or future speculation/assumption: "He would have finished this job by 2024", i.e. I am not sure but I assume that he will have finished this job by 2024.

Comment: @Eugene The "would have lived here" sentence is great as-is:  that is *exactly the right construction* for expressing the future irrealis, since he *didn't* actually remain there for the full 5 years.  The "would have finished this job" sentence does *not* sound idiomatic though, because the possibility is still open that he might finish the job by 2024.  I would change the second sentence to, "He may finish this job by 2024."  **may** is the primary word for expressing present or future possibility, although "might" could also be used (less formally?):  "He might finish this job by 2024."

Comment: As matter of fact, rereading my previous comment, "might" actually sounds better in the second example for the context of a casual conversation, and 'may' *might* be a bit too formal!  The version with 'may' seems more likely to be used in written communication.

Comment: @Eugene Also, in the alternate scenario where the person didn't leave a month ago, and where the possibility of him living there for 5 consecutive years still exists, you could say, "He **will have lived** here for 5 years **as of** 2024 if he **doesn't leave** next month."  "Will have lived" is the *future perfect indicative*, and *as of* is a standard way of expressing "time by which."

Comment: @Quack E. Duck Would the second sentence sound well if rewritten in the way Kate Bunting proposed hereinbefore: "I am confident that he would have finished this job by 2024."?

Comment: @Eugene Yes, but **only if** the time at which the sentence is said happens to be **after** the year 2024.  "I am confident that he would have finished this job by 2024" is valid if said in 2025, but not in 2023.

Comment: @Eugene Before 2024, to express confidence that the job will be in a completed state by that time, you could say either "I am confident that he **will finish** this job by 2024" (more common) or "I am confident that he **will have finished** this job by 2024" (less common, but puts more emphasis on the completion of the job).  Note that neither sentence uses "would"!

Comment: "Would" does not belong in the future **unless** you're expressing something that's **impossible**.

Comment: @Quack E. Duck I see. "Might" and "could" wouldn't be possible either? As in: "He might/could have finished this job by 2025."?

Comment: @Eugene You are correct, those versions also seem to be talking about the past (or an impossible situation) even though the date is in the future.

Comment: @Quack E. Duck Thank you very much for your profound and qualitative elucidation!

Comment: @Eugene You're welcome!  I'm glad I was able to help :)